# Error creating extension attribute of date datatype in azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to create an extension attribute in azure b2c for storing user's dateofBirth using Graph API. Getting below error when trying to use 'date' datatype:
Request Body:
{
"name": "dateOfBirth",
"dataType": "date",
"targetObjects": ["User"]
}

Response:"error": {
"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid value specified for property 'dataType' of resource 'ExtensionProperty'.".

Is date not an accepted datatype for extension variables?
Is there any alternate way to create extension attribute for custom policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official AD B2C document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#create-a-custom-attribute),

> Choose a Data Type. Only String, Boolean, and Int are available.

I think for your case, you can create a string extension attribute and store the date as String. For the way to create string extension attribute, just refer to the above link of official document.

Comment: Thanks. Yes since I have a requirement to split Date, Month & Year from the DateofBirth, it makes sense to store it as a string extension attribute. But can I still have a DateTimeDropdown on the UI for user to enter Date Of Birth field? I believe if extension attribute is of string type, only option is to show a textbox

Comment: That might be hard for out-of-the-box features. You might submit them as claims to your own RESTful API for processing and save it as String type using graph API.